# PgBouncer peer & host authentication for the same database

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have a `PgBouncer` installed on the same host with postgres server and I have several scenarios for it:

1. Monitoring(`pgwatch2`) should connect with `peer` authentication to the `postgres`(for example) database via `PgBouncer`
2. External client connection should also be able connect to the database postgres via `PgBouncer`(with `host` authentication method)

I can't understand how to properly configure `PgBouncer` to follow the rules:

1. If the connection to `PgBouncer` is done via socket, it should proceed with `peer` authentication to the postgres server
2. If the connection uses the `host` authentication method, `PgBouncer` should also connect to postgres server with the corresponding `host` method

My current configuration is as follows, but it doesn't choose socket or localhost properly(sometimes it fails):

```
[databases]
* = host=localhost port=5432
* = host=/tmp port=5432
```

I added two different rules to fix my issues, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: Why does the monitoring need to use pgbouncer?  Just bypass it and go right to the database by specifying the port.  Any monitoring solution so poorly written that it *needs* pgbouncer is one I would not be using.

Comment: it's the monitoring of pgbouncer, so all connections should go through it to call `show stats;`

Comment: oh, I see.  In that case, does it need to connect through to the database at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't distinguish pools based on the incoming connection type.  You could create a fake database entry, and then direct it to the real database in the config:

```
[databases]
monitoring_database = host=/tmp dbname=postgres port=5432
* =                   host=localhost port=5432
```

But in this case the peer authentication would be coming from the owner of the pgbouncer process, not from the owner of the monitoring client.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different database user for the monitoring system, and create a special one-session pool for it. If your monitoring system is smart enough to keep the database connection open, do without pgBouncer and let the monitoring system connect to the database directly.

Comment: But my new monitoring user still needs to be able to connect to database `postgres` due to the monitoring service logics. I need several rules, like `postgres= host = localhost port=5432` and `postgres= host = /tmp port = 5432`

Comment: I am not certain what you mean by that comment.